# Get a value from a map once it is filled with Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm new to Hazelcast and am struggling with, in my opinion, a pretty simple problem, however not able to solve it.

I have this scenario, I have 2 webservices where in one server (1st API) I have to get a value that is going to be populated after 5 seconds from a different server using a 2nd API, and I only have a referenceId between both servers to identify/get/populate the values. In other words, when my 1st Api is invoked with and ID, it will return what is pushed to a 2nd Api with that ID.

This diagram shows better what I want to solve by connecting 1st and 2nd APIs:
[image]

So, I have used an IMap and do a 'get' and 'put' like this:

```
//- First API -//
Integer referenceId = XXXX; // coming in the step 2
IMap<Integer, String> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("ResponseMap");

Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep here does the trick but it's the worst performance
String strResponse = map.get(referenceId);
```

On the other hand, the other server is going to put the data after up to 5 seconds like this:

```
//- Second API -//
String refId = captureRefId(YYYY)
IMap<Integer, String> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("ResponseMap");
map.put(refId, YYYY);
```

The problem with this is that map.get returns always null since the value doesn't exist at that moment, however if I add a `sleep(5)` everything works fine.

My question is, how can I do to do a `map.get(referenceId)` to be blocked until the other server populates the map with that specific id? Is there another better choice than using IMap?

Comment: Wouldn't a poll loop, with a few millis waiting time, solve the issue? Not sure I totally understood your question / issue. IMap does not have such a blocking operation and maybe IQueue would solve it better but it depends on what you really want to achieve. Maybe you can elaborate further.

Comment: @noctarius thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with a diagram. It shows better my problem where I want to have `1st API` waiting for `2nd API` to be executed and populate the data.

Comment: Still, doesn't polling solves the issue? As an alternative, a map listener?

Comment: @noctarius I'm quite new to HZ, so never used polling nor map listener. Could you point me to a sample? Or actually with an answer? Btw, by polling do you mean IQueue? I was investigating a map listener but didn't find how to connect the data through the reference Id (keep in mind that 2nd API exists in multiple servers

Answer (score 2):

As @noctarius mentioned an EntryListener would be the best approach if you necessarily want to use an IMap. Here's an example how an EntryListener works.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/distributed-map/entry-listener/src/main/java/ListeningMember.java

You subscribe and get notified whenever an entry is added. Then you can fire your logic.

Comment: Did you have any chance to evaluate the answer? As said, with the IMap it's the only way to do it.